# Insert node and write inside

Tags: javascript

I have a contenteditable div and I would like to wrap its content into a `span`.

I have this function which is called on div focus:

```
focusOnCommentInput(event: any) {
    let element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    if(event.target.textContent.trim().length === 0){
        event.target.innerHTML = '';
        let range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        let selection = window.getSelection();
        let textNode = document.createElement('span');
        range.insertNode(textNode);
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Now the `span` is actually inserted but the caret doesn't move inside

[image: Hello World]

How to focus on the span ?

Comment: `if(event.target.textContent.trim().length === 0){` so you want to select the content of the element only when it is empty?

Comment: Are you trying to make a code editor of sort of that?

Comment: @Thomas No I want to insert a span when it is empty and let user write inside the span

Comment: @Maheer not really a text editor

Comment: `caret` cannot move inside `<span>` because its not editable

Comment: Add a `textarea` or an `input` insteand of a span, then you can use `elem.focus()`